# If H is a subset of G, prove that H is also a subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

$G$ is a group, and $H$ is a nonempty subset of $G$. We know that, for any two values $a$ and $b$ in $H$, $ab^{-1}$ is also in $H$. Given this, how do we know that $H$ is also a subgroup of $G$? More specifically, I need help proving that, for every $a$ in $H$, $a^{-1}$ is also in $H$. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if $H$ is nonempty, at least there is some element $a \in H$. Can you conclude that there are more elements in $H$ with only that?

Comment: Note that given any $a\in H$, $a\cdot a^{-1}=1\in H$. And, for any $a\in H, 1\cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1}\in H$. And, for any $a,b\in H$, $b^{-1}\in H\to a(b^{-1})^{-1}=ab\in H$. This is sufficient.

Comment: $\forall a,b\in H, ab^{-1}\in H$ implies $aa^{-1}=e \in H$ and thus $ea^{-1}=a^{-1} \in H$

Answer (score 1):

To show $h^{-1}$ is in $H$ for all $h\in H$, note that the given property implies:
$hh^{-1} =e \in H$. But now letting $e$ take the role of $a$ and $h$ take the role of $b$ above we get that:

$eh^{-1} =h^{-1}\in H$

Answer (score 0):

Since $H$ is nonempty, there is some $a \in H$. Now, $aa^{-1} = 1$ is also an element of $H$. Also, since $1 \in H$ and $a \in H$, so is $1\cdot a^{-1} = a^{-1}$. Lastly, if $a,b \in H$, then $b^{-1} \in H$ and thus $a(b^{-1})^{-1} = ab \in H$.

Comment: I think there is at least some circular logic going on in premise 2 and 3. Are you sure about these? And I would have called the identity element, $e$ and not $1$ but maybe that's a stylistic thing...