# $(H, *)$ is a subgroup of $G$ $\iff$ $a,b\in H $ implies $ab^{-1}\in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, predicate-logic

[Duplicate? This question is not simply asking for a proof, it deals with the **logical structure of the proof**, and particularly, with the use of sustitutions in relation with quantifiers.]

---

Although Burton's Introduction To Abstract Mathematical Systems is
the most reader-friendly elementary book on abstract algebra, the
proof it gives of the above theorem is to me difficult
to understand, more precisely, in it's second part,
dealing with the reverse implication:

> If $a,b\in H$ implies $ab^{-1}\in H$  then  $(H, *)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Could anyone give a proof with an endeavour at making as clear
as possible the **logical structure** of the argument? A proof
using the natural deduction method would be much appreciated.

More precisely, what makes standard proofs of this theorem difficult
is the use of substitutions that seem arbitrary and *ad hoc*: the
underlying mechanism is not made explicit in terms of quantifiers and instantiation.

The theorem reads as follows:

> Suppose that $(G,*)$ is a group and $H$ is a non-empty subset of $G$.
>
> Then $(H, *)$ is a subgroup of $G$  if and only if $a,b\in H$ implies $ab^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: One has to assume that $H$ is also nonempty.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added this condition in the body of the question.

Comment: This is the subgroup criterion.

Comment: That's right. It gives a necessary and sufficient condition for H to be a subgoup of G.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If H is a subset of G, prove that H is also a subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161151/if-h-is-a-subset-of-g-prove-that-h-is-also-a-subgroup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One direction is clear and I'll leave it to you to flesh out the details. As for the other direction . . .

**Associativity** of the operation in $H$ is inherited from that of $G$. (Showing this rigourously is a matter of restricting the domain of a predicate. Can you see why?)

Since $H$ is nonempty, there exists an $x\in H$ (by existential instantiation). Thus to prove that the **identity** is in $H$, we have $xx^{-1}=e\in H$ (by letting $a=b=x$ via universal instantiation).

Since now $e\in H$, we have for any $x\in H$ that $ex^{-1}=x^{-1}\in H$ (by letting $a=e, b=x$ via universal instantiation). Hence $H$ is closed under taking **inverses**.

For **closure** of $H$ under the operation, if $x,y\in H$, let $a=x, b=y^{-1}$ via universal instantiation. Then $x(y^{-1})^{-1}=xy\in H$.

Hence $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thanks  Shaun. Sure any  competent mathematician will say this proof is correct  and also elegant. What makes it difficult to me is the fact that substitutions ( for example : " let a=e , b=x) are taken as obvious to understand.". When I read it, the objection comes into my mind: " how can you give specific values to your variables, values that lead to the result you want? " That's why I was asking for a proof that would make clear even for beginners the logical structure, and more particuliarly, the use of quantifiers.

Comment: the idea is that what we are allowed to assume is that for **all** possible choices of $a$ and $b$ in $H$, then $ab$ is also in $H$. So if we have specific values for these "variables", then our assumption allows us to conclude in specific. This is the power of our assumption. What you should think, whenever you have this kind of assumption, is that you want to "cash in" on it for specific (or general) examples in order to draw conclusions, exactly as we have done here.

Comment: Helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It's a matter of [universal instantiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation), @RayLittleRock; I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this precision.

Comment: You're welcome, @RayLittleRock. Please don't forget to accept this answer if it is sufficient for you :)

Comment: I meant , thanks for this point.  ( "Precision" can be used in french for "point"...).

Comment: @Shaun . Answer accepted !

Comment: What's the reason for talking about associativity?

Comment: You're right, @egreg; I suppose it is a bit pedantic of me. I'll leave it there for completeness (although, having said that, there is at least one thing I omitted: the fact that $H\subseteq G$ needs a mention if I'm going to be thorough).

Comment: @Shaun I'd detract points to a student's paper for that. `;-)`